# How to attach an image to source file?

Tags: java, ide, documentation

Is there a way or IDE which enables attaching images (or any other media) to source codes. This would be great for documenting as it is more powerful to represent knowledge and faster to understand from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include images in javadoc, which Eclipse will show in popups and javadoc view, but not in source. I'm not aware of any IDE which will show images inline with source.

You need to put your image file in a 'doc-files' folder and reference it like a regular html image:

```
/**
 * <img src="./doc-files/image.png" />
 */
```